# What is this lawn weed with cut-edged leaves and five petaled pink-purple flowers, found in Belgium?

Tags: identification, lawn, weed-control, weeds

I have recently had to move, and we have a lawn that has not been taken care of for some time. Due to this it's about 30% grass, with the rest being assorted weeds/wildflowers.

I've managed to identify most of them but I'm having trouble with this one, and want to know if it's something I need to take care of now, or if it's harmless.

It branches outwards from a central point, has a tap root and when the flowers are open they have 5 sepals, 5 petals and are a deep pink-purple color. They may have flowered before in late May, but due to the mix of plants it's possible it was something else.
The soil here is very loose and sandy and the plant is growing in full sun.

[image: Mystery weed]

Edit: after some rain the flowers all seem to have come out nicely so here's an example. The camera I used seems to have changed the hue to be a bit less pink though. I don't know how noticeable it is in the picture but for every flower two petals seem to have a dark spot near the base and a deeper color than the other three. I have also included a branch with the leaves less clustered so that you can see the alternating pattern of the leaves.
[image: Flowers]
[image: Leaves]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it, or something very similar: Erodium cicutarium, known here as reigersbek (heron's beak) but storks bill in English. It seems that the main danger here is from the seeds as they are quite easy to pull up.
(Found [here](http://www.wildebloemen.info/pages%20bloemen/R/reigersbek.php))